# How to develop a Query Refinement tool using C# / Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Want to develop a query refinement tool just like Google Suggest so that i will get recommended options when i enter keywords in the search textbox i.e( if i type "car"
i will get the recommended options as rental cars,used cars,cars for sale etc) want to develop the tool in c#/ASP.Net dont know where to start.please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using javascript and let's say some web service / page method. You send the values that user gave you to a web service. The web service translates the text, make some database (or other storage) request and return the results to the page as json (or some other format that suits you).

Look at this article if you need some example code:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515

By the way, if you need more articles, just put "asp.net autocomplete" into Google. That should give you plenty of resources.